# Connecting peers doesn't work as expected - PeerJS

Tags: meteor, webrtc, peerjs

I am building audio calling application using [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com). In the call receiver, I have the following code inside `peer.on('call', function(call) { ... }`:

```
var conn = peer.connect(call.peer);

var receiveCall = bootbox.dialog({
   className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
   closeButton: false,
   animate: true,
   title: 'Call Recieved',
   message: "Accept or Decline",
   onEscape: null,
   buttons: {
    pickup: {
     label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Answer",
     className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
     callback: function(){
      conn.send('ACCEPT') // send ACCEPT to the other client
      window.currentCall = call;
      call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
      call.on('stream', function(remoteStream) {
        var audio = $('<audio autoplay />').appendTo('body');
        audio[0].src = (URL || webkitURL || mozURL).createObjectURL(stream);
      });
      return false;
    }
  },
  hangup: {
    label: "<i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Decline",
    className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
    callback: function(){
      conn.send('DECLINED') // send DECLINED to the other client
      window.currentCall.close()
      stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
      return false;
    }
  }
}
});
```

I can see the data is successfully received to the other client (the client who made the call). I am using the following code to receive the data:

```
callDialog.init(function(){
        peer.on('connection', function(conn) {
            conn.on('data', function(data){

                console.log(call);
                if(data == "ACCEPT"){
                    $("#test").text("This is dynamic msg");
                    $("#hangup").text("Hangup");

                } else if (data == "DECLINED"){
                    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }
});
        });
    });
```

The problem is here that I am using the same code in the client who is making the call to send data to the call receiver but it doesn't work and no error is showing in the console.

This is the code in the call initializer client:

```
var conn = peer.connect(destinationPeerId);

var callDialog = bootbox.dialog({
        title: 'Making Call',
        message: '<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i><span id="test"> Waiting for Reply... </span></div>',
        onEscape: null,
        buttons: {
            hangup: {
                label: "<span id='hangup' <i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> Cancel </span>",
                className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
                callback: function(){
                    conn.send('DECLINED'); // sent to the call receiver
                    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Why the same code sends data from the call receiver to the initializer, but not the other way around?

And how should I go with it to be able to send data the other way around?